# Redrawing Highcharts after service call - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I've AngularJS Application using Highcharts JS v5.0.10.
I've drawn line and stacked column charts with initial data.

but When I change some parameters in application, and I'm making REST call, and it's successful with JSON response. Highcharts are not reloading/redrawing with changed data, It shows me chart with same old initial data.

How could I redraw chart once I receive server response ? Need JS Side solution.

EDIT : I'm not using Highcharts-ng directive, so another duplicate question is not solving my problem - Already tried that.

Comment: could you add the code snippet of your problem?

Comment: @Und3rTow No, In other question author is using highcharts-ng directive by pablojim, where in my case I've my own directive.

Comment: @ngDev I recommend updating your question to include the relevant code, it would make it a lot easier to determine where your issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $scope.$watch for checking data change in highchart. Inside that function we need to call chart.redraw()

Comment: 'chart'  will be Highchart object, right ? I should be getting that in directive only ?

Comment: If you have defined Highcharts object in the directive then yes you can use chart.redraw in directive itself

Comment: In my case, I've redrawn charts with 

 Highcharts.chart(element, seriesObject);

It's same trick but different way to do it. 
Thank you PRADEEP KUMAR